# NextJS API response content is not showing in page view source

Tags: next.js

We need Server Side Rendering (SSR) for a website and using NextJS for it. The page content is dynamic and getting page content from API. and page content is displaying fine when viewing as normal url but not displaying the page content in browser view source of a URL (Right click -> View page source [view-source:url]) of that url. Here the dynamic page content is not rendering.

here is the code -

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import {API_BASE_URL} from '../Config/Settings'
import SideBar from '../Layouts/SideBar'
import Link from "next/link"
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import axios from 'axios'



export const CmsPage = (props) => {

    const [PageHtmlContent, setPageContent] = useState('');
    const [PageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState('');
    const [PageDescription, setPageDescription] = useState('');
    const [SeoKeyword,setSeoKeyword]=useState('');

    useEffect( async() => {
        let body={pageTypeCode:props.pageType,pageName:props.pageName};
        const config =
        {
            headers:
            {
                'x-auth-token':"rpsite-public-token" 
            }
        }
        try {
            const res= await axios.post(API_BASE_URL+'/api/cms/page',body,config);
           // alert(res.data.content);
           setPageContent(res.data.content);
           setPageTitle(res.data.seoTitle);
           setPageDescription(res.data.seoDescription);
           setSeoKeyword(res.data.seoKeyword);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            setPageContent('<b>Something went wrong!</b>');
        }
    
      },[props]);
    return (
        <section class="inner-body-section">
              <Head>
               <title>{PageTitle}</title>
               <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
               <meta name="keywords" content={SeoKeyword} />
               <meta name="description" content={PageDescription}/>
             </Head>
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <SideBar/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                           <div className="inner-body-content">
                                <div id="contentBlock" className="page-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:PageHtmlContent}}></div>
                                </div>
                           </div> 
                        </div>
                </div>
       </section>  
    )
}

export default CmsPage;
```

I want to render the full page content in view source also. Can you please help.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)?

Comment: Yes it worked with getServerSideProps. but json data also displaying along with page content in view source. like <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props"..... "buildId":"development","isFallback":false,"gssp":true,"customServer":true}</script>

How to avoid to display json response in page view source?

Comment: Can't be avoided. That's required for Next.js to hydrate the page on the client.